# The right way to use a PHP backend serving oauth tokens to a Javascript frontend sending credentials?

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, token, response

I know Javascript but I don't know PHP. Through some tutorials, I build a basic PHP server hosted on an AWS EC2 Linux environment. I've built a simple PHP script that sends a post request to an external API to get a token with correct credentials. My Javascript does a typical fetch post to the PHP server with correct credentials. The response I get is a response object with a body that has a readableStream object with key/value `locked: false`. I've never seen this before.

Here is my PHP code with credentials disguised:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");


    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $post_array = array(
        'partnerName' => '<partner name hardcoded>',
        'partnerPassword' => '<password hardcoded>',
        'partnerUserID' => $email, // param passed from frontend
        'partnerUserSecret' => $password // same here
    );
    postAuth($post_array);



function postAuth($post_array){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, '<address to external site to get auth token>');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $result;
}
```

And here is my Javascript:

```
const authApi = async () => {
  const data = {
    email: "<email required to get auth token>",
    password: "<password required to get auth token>",
  };
    const response = await fetch("<php server address>", {
        method: "post",
        data: data,
    })
    console.log(response)
};

authApi()
```

Comment: This is not far to work as it, but I think it's worth reading about jwt. Quite easy to implement, however it's safer to use libraries. https://jwt.io/introduction